# Makefile define variable using if

Tags: shell, makefile

I'm trying to do something like it

```
@if[[ 1==1 ]] then;\
   COMPILER_CMD = -fPic;\
fi;
```

But if i call in the next line the variable it don't work.
If i define it outside the if it works perfect.
Someone can help me?

Comment: @Oli: he's defining a shell variable in the recipe, which won't work  as each line is independent if `.ONESHELL:` isn't present; I'm 99% sure that there's a better solution to the problem, though

Comment: @demonofnight: what are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: If i just try to print the variable after the if the variable is empty

Comment: @Christoph: That would be true if there were no line-continuation characters.  I think the real problem is the whitespace in the variable declaration.

Comment: @Oli: there is no backslash after the final line -- if his `print` comes on its own line, it won't see the variable; you're probably right about the whitespace, though...

Comment: I need to put the backslash, if i don't put it says i need a delimiter.

Comment: [[ is not valid in all shells.  If you use that construct, you must tell make to use a shell that will recognize it.  eg, SHELL=/bin/bash

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As *everyone* is saying, you haven't given us enough information. But I'll make a guess. You want to set this variable conditionally, then use it elsewhere in the makefile, and in other makefiles which `include` this one.

The trouble is that you are trying to use shell syntax. In a *command* this will work (if the syntax is correct), but the value will apply only in that command. Outside commands, shell syntax is just wrong and will cause an error, malfunction, or be ignored depending on exactly what you do.

Try this in the makefile, outside of any rule (that is, not in the recipe for any particular target):

```
ifeq (1,1)
COMPILER_CMD = -fPic
endif

$(info $(COMPILER_CMD))
```

If that works, then you can try to adapt it to do whatever it is you're actually trying to do.

Comment: id i add those lines to my makefile i receive the missing separator error.

Comment: @demonofnight, *show us the makefile*. And tell us which version of Make you're using (`make -v`).

Comment: Solved, i forgot the empty space

Answer (score 1):

Each line in the Makefile is executed separately in a new shell process, so that's why changes you made to the environment are not propagated to next line.

You can combine both lines into one long one to achieve what you want. You probably have something like this in you Makefile:

```
@if[[ 1==1 ]] then;\
   COMPILER_CMD = -fPic;\
fi;
echo $COMPILER_CMD
```

You want to add the line continuation backslash to the line before echo:

```
@if[[ 1==1 ]] then;\
   COMPILER_CMD = -fPic;\
fi; \
echo $COMPILER_CMD
```

Comment: Okay, but if i need it in in another script that includes this script. This script is a script just to define the variable, the compile process is another script that uses those variables, how i'll do that if i need to do that in the same line?

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming that the example you show is the recipe for some rule.  By the syntax here it looks like you're trying to set a make variable COMPILER_CMD from within a recipe based on the value of some shell boolean test, which is of course impossible.  You have to be very clear in your mind how make works: make is not interpreting the recipes you write, in any way.  Make is simply passing those recipes to another program (the shell) and the other program is interpreting those commands.  Thus, you can't change the behavior of make, including setting make variables, from within a recipe: that recipe is being run in a completely different program.

As others have said, you don't give enough information about what you REALLY want to do, at a higher level, for us to give a complete solution.  Having a boolean like `1==1` doesn't give any hint whatsoever as to why you're doing this.  Also your shell syntax contains syntax errors, so we can tell you didn't actually cut and paste this from a real, working example.

You can, as piokuc implies, use a shell variable COMPILER_CMD (you have to remove the whitespace around the `=` to make it a shell variable assignment) but that value takes effect only while that one recipe line is running.  For the next recipe line a new shell is started and any values set in the previous shell are lost:

```
all:
        @ if [[ 1 == 1 ]]; then COMPILER_CMD=-fpic; fi; \
          echo COMPILER_CMD=$$COMPILER_CMD
        @ echo COMPILER_CMD=$$COMPILER_CMD
```

will give:

```
COMPILER_CMD=-fpic
COMPILER_CMD=
```

Comment: "Not interpreting in any way" is too broad: of course make will expand any macro references in the recipe before sending it to the shell.  But once the string is expanded and passed to the shell, make knows nothing more about it.  It just waits for the shell to finish, checks the exit code to see if it succeeded or failed, and moves on.